# Cannot load Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects module in Qt 6.3

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt6

I'm using the [Qt 5 Core Compatibility APIs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcore5-index.html) in my Qt 6 applications. In particular, I need the [QtGraphicalEffects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgraphicaleffects-index.html) module in my Qt Quick Scene.

This is the full code of my main.qml file:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item {
        width: 300
        height: 300

        Image {
            id: bug
            source: "images/bug.jpg"
            sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
            smooth: true
            visible: false
        }

        Image {
            id: mask
            source: "images/butterfly.png"
            sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
            smooth: true
            visible: false
        }

        OpacityMask {
            anchors.fill: bug
            source: bug
            maskSource: mask
        }
    }
}
```

This runs fine with Qt 6.2.4 (installed via the Qt Maintenance Tool). However with Qt 6.3.0, I get the following error:

> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
> qrc:/main.qml:3:1: Cannot load library C:\Qt\6.3.0\msvc2019_64\qml\Qt5Compat\GraphicalEffects\qtgraphicaleffectsplugind.dll: The specified procedure could not be found.

I verified that the file `C:\Qt\6.3.0\msvc2019_64\qml\Qt5Compat\GraphicalEffects\qtgraphicaleffectsplugind.dll` actually exists and made sure that the Qt 5 Compatibility module is installed for my Qt version. I've also tried to upgrade to the Qt 6.4.0 alpha release (again making sure that the compatibility module is installed) and with that I get a slightly different error:

> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
> qrc:/main.qml:31:9: Type OpacityMask unavailable
> qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/Qt5Compat/GraphicalEffects/OpacityMask.qml:41:1: Cannot load library C:\Qt\6.4.0\msvc2019_64\qml\Qt5Compat\GraphicalEffects\private\qtgraphicaleffectsprivateplugind.dll: The specified module could not be found.

What could be the cause of this issue? Has anything changed since Qt 6.3.0 regarding the compatibility module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [this thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/139931/qt5compat-missing-module/3) said, You need install `Shader tools` module after `Qt 6.4`. Install it by MaintenanceTool, then it will be ok.

Comment: Installing "Qt Shader Tools" fix the error for me, thanks.